# deploy dash application on google cloud with python using multiple scripts

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Dash application on python that is running locally on my computer. I am trying to deploy the dash application on google cloud. I am new to google cloud. The issue I am having is the dash application python file (app.py) need to trigger 3 other python files to run simultaneously and write a csv file save into the directory so (app.py) the main dash application file will read the csv file and get the information this works locally on my laptop but i need to know a way to implement this in google cloud and host the dash application. how would i implement this on google cloud

Comment: How are you getting 3 python files to run concurrently with the app.py file locally? What are those files doing? Are they connected to a data source and creating a csv file? Can you somehow run those from within your app.py file before serving the app? More info would be helpful in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following the instructions outlined by @Federico Tartarini in his excellent [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VewIO2Yhmo) on Deploying a plotly dash app to Google Cloud.

Using his video as a guide, I deployed a [plotly dash app](https://www.derekoconn.com/projects/trig-least-squares-app) on my personal website, and the repo is [here](https://github.com/merillium/trig_least_squares) – feel free to take a look as that may provide some additional guidance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information i followed that video the was able to create a cloud run project and it deploy but i need to also run the 3 python files in the background how would i do that? because the 3 python scripts send information to the main app.py file